# Cannot cancel copy task in ESXi Web interface

Tags: vmware-esxi, copy

I started copying a file from one datastore to another using the ESXi Web interface (version 6.5.0 Update 1 (Build 6765664)) and has been going on for half a day. I want to gracefully stop the copying process but it does not seem to let me. Any ideas? I could ssh into the box to kill the process if that's the only way.

Thanks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDxKA.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Esxi only, not ESX: Restart the VM client daemon after SSH Login

```
/etc/init.d/hostd restart
```

Comment: Works on ESXi 6.7

Comment: Works on 6.5.0 U2

Comment: Interesting that canceling a benign task like that involves killing the service.

Comment: Works on ESXi 6.7 U2

Comment: Works on ESXi 7.0.0 (Build 15843807) too